# SQL Server's Equivalent in MySQL's binary log

Tags: sql-server, transaction

Is there any MySQL's binary log equivalent in SQL Server.If yes, how can we retrieve data changes(with data) from that log and store it in a table or in a file? I cant enable CDC since I am using SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition. Kindly suggest.

Comment: I think this question is too broad, have a look at [SQL Server DDL Triggers to Track All Database Changes](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/)

Comment: Every database has a log file that stores the changes made to data. But 1) it is "cleared" on checkpoints if you are in simple recovery model and after log backup if you are in full/bulk logged 2) it's difficult to take info out of this because it's not supposed to (there is undocumented fn_dblog() function though). You can use cdc if you have Enterprise Edition to track data changes in comfortable way: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-cdc-in-sql-server-2008/

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server's transaction log is for SQL Server's internal uses, and Microsoft doesn't really give us an API to use it for other purposes.

For SQL Server 2012, the closest built-in tool is the [undocumented fn_dump_dblog function](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/) (linking to a Paul Randal post - former developer at Microsoft), but make sure you read about the gotchas in there about hidden worker threads that don't go away. I wouldn't rely on that for regular data change polling.

If you describe your business goal in more detail (what you want to do with the data changes), you'll get better answers about the right feature or third party tool to use instead. For example, if you're looking for compliance auditing, there's one set of tools, but if you're looking to debug an application, I'd recommend a different set of tools.